# Why ContourPlot shows nothing when use "ReplaceAll"?

Tags: plotting, rule

When I use `ReplaceAll` in `ContourPlot`, it shows me nothing:

```
ContourPlot[y == k x /. {k->0.4}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

Without `ContourPlot` it works

```
ContourPlot[y == 0.4 x , {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE. Start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always [edit] if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include minimal working example of your code and data in [formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX). By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers. The site depends on participation, as you receive **give back:** vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: Your question may be put [on-hold](https://goo.gl/jXYaiD) as it seems to be [off-topic](https://goo.gl/bnZVrD), i.e it arises from a simple mistake easily found in the documentation and is unlikely to help any future visitors. Please **don't be discouraged** by that cleaning-up policy. You got your answer and your future [good questions](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3) are always welcome. Learn about [common pitfalls here](https://goo.gl/XAcNDp).

Comment: Try: `ContourPlot[y == (k x /. k -> 0.4), {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]`

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Thanks, that helped! I still don't get why we need to change operation order, shouldn't the substitution applied to the whole formula `y == k x` work just as well?

Comment: @monk-time.Try: `ContourPlot[Evaluate[y == k x /. k -> 0.4], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]` or:                        `k = 0.4; ContourPlot[y == k x, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Evaluate` to force the replacement.

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[y == k x /. {k -> 0.4}], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```